# Can the following trick be expanded upon?

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, taylor-expansion, fractional-calculus

### Main Question

What is the expansion of $d^{1+\epsilon}?$

### Background

I noticed the following trick (sometimes more laborious) to directly differentiate $ f(x) $ twice without differentiating it even once.

To show what I mean let $ f(x)=x^2 $

By Taylor expansion for any $f(x)$ :

**Equation 1**

$$ f(x+ \epsilon ) = f(x) + \epsilon f'(x) + \frac{\epsilon^2 f''(x)}{2!} + ...  $$

**Equation 2**

$$ f(x+ \epsilon ) = (x+ \epsilon )^2 = ... + \epsilon^2 $$

Comparing the $ \epsilon^2 $ term in equation $1 $and $2 $ we get:

$$ \frac{f''(x)}{2!} = 1$$

Hence,

$$ f''(x) = 2 $$

### Question

Can similar reasoning be applied for $ d^{1+\epsilon} g(x) $ where $g(x)$ is a dummy function to reveal the entire space of $ (d^n g(x)) $ on $g(x)$ ?

Comment: It seems your method requires you to A. know the Taylor expansion for f(x) (at least to some specified order) and B. know how to work with f(x+$\epsilon$) algebraically.  That's a lot more information than just the second derivative!  Or have I misread the question?  Can you handle, say, Sin(x) by your method (even if you are given the Taylor expansion for SIn(x)?)

Comment: This is a clever observation but you are going to run into an issue finding the $n^{th}$ derivative if your expansion of $f(x + \epsilon)$ doesn't have an $\epsilon^n$ term.  Humorously enough, the easiest way to find such a term for a nonpolynomial function might be to make a Taylor series :).

Comment: @lulu Which is why I wrote "(sometimes more laborious)" (maybe I should have been most of the time more laborious)  ... The advantage of this method is that it lets one see the entire space of derivatives of any arbitrary function ... For $ sin(x) $ We do the following: $sin(x+ \epsilon)= \sin(x) \cos \epsilon + \sin( \epsilon) \cos (x) $ And then we Taylor expand both $  \sin( \epsilon) $ and $ \cos \epsilon $ .... Anyhow the main question I'm interested in is what would the space of $ d^n g(x) $ look like ....

Comment: This should work for polynomials, but it's unlikely to be reasonable for any other function.

Comment: This is rather similar to use of [dual numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_number#Differentiation) in automatic differentiation.

Comment: @Budenn Whoa! never thought of making $ \epsilon $ a matrix .... Is there also anything similar to my question: What is the expansion of $ d^{1+ \epsilon} $ ?

Comment: @AnantSaxena Not sure, something like that would probably fall under [fractional calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_calculus), which I'm not familiar with.

Comment: Is $\epsilon$ supposed to be a positive real, or a positive integer?

Comment: There's a cute way of deriving Taylor series from exponential operators:

\begin{align*}
e^{\epsilon d}f(x) &= \left(1+\epsilon d +\frac{\epsilon^2 d^2}{2!}+\frac{\epsilon^3d^3}{3!}+\cdots\right)f(x)\\
&=f(x)+f'(x)\epsilon+f''(x)\frac{\epsilon^2}{2!}+f'''(x)\frac{\epsilon^3}{3!}+...
\end{align*}

Thus, if you can make sense of $d^{1+\delta}$, through say, fractional calculus, the above operator would give you the expansion you desire.

Comment: In the book: S.G. Samko, A.A. Kilbas and O.I. Marinchev, *Fractional integrals and derivatives: theory and applications*, Gordon & Breach Science Publishers, 1993, the authors present a Taylor expansion for the differentiation operator. However, this approach suffers from several pathologies and is not much used (as far as I know). However, such fractional-order expansions are well studied. See for example: H. Komatsu, *Fractional powers of operators*, Pac. J. Math 21, 1967.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you mean to expand

$$
d^{1+\epsilon} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k d^k.
$$

In general

$$
d^{1+\epsilon} = \big(1 + d - 1\big)^{1+\epsilon} = \sum_{\ell=0}^\infty \binom{1+\epsilon}{\ell} \big(d-1\big)^\ell
$$

So

$$
d^{1+\epsilon} = \big(1 + d - 1\big)^{1+\epsilon} = \sum_{\ell=0}^\infty \binom{1+\epsilon}{\ell}
\sum_{k=0}^\ell \binom{\ell}{k} (-1)^{\ell-k} d^k\\
= \sum_{\ell=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^\ell 
\binom{1+\epsilon}{\ell} \binom{\ell}{k} (-1)^{\ell-k} d^k\\
= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left( \sum_{\ell=k}^\infty \binom{1+\epsilon}{\ell} \binom{\ell}{k} (-1)^{\ell-k} \right) d^k.
$$

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear to me what you are asking; I shall assume that you are asking for a method allowing one to find $f^{(n)} (x_0)$ without computing the derivatives of lower order.

Since your example uses Taylor series, let us restrict to the case when $f$ is real-analytic on $(a,b)$. Then $f$ [admits an extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_function#Alternative_characterizations) $F : D = \mathring D \subset \Bbb C \to \Bbb C$, with $(a,b) \subset D$ and $F$ complex-analytic. Now, choose a simple closed contour $\gamma \subset D$ surrounding $x_0 \in (a,b)$. Then, according to [Cauchy's integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula#Theorem), $f^{(n)} (x_0) = \frac {n!} {2 \pi \Bbb i} \oint \limits _\gamma \frac {f(z)} {(z-x_0) ^{n+1}} \Bbb d z$ with $\gamma$ oriented counterclockwisely.

For $f$ being no longer analytic, but smooth and absolutely integrable on $\Bbb R$, another approach would be to use a basic idea from the theory of the [Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Functional_relationships). If $\widehat f (p) = \frac 1 {\sqrt {2 \pi}} \int \limits _{- \infty} ^\infty \Bbb e ^{- \Bbb i p x} f(x) \Bbb d x$ then one can prove that $\widehat {f^{(n)}} (p) = (\Bbb i p)^n \widehat f (p)$, so that $f^{(n)}$ can be obtained with the aid of the inverse Fourier transform: $f^{(n)} (x) = \frac 1 {\sqrt {2 \pi}} \int \limits _{- \infty} ^\infty \Bbb e ^{ \Bbb i p x} (\Bbb i p)^n \widehat f (p) \Bbb d p$.

A similar result could be obtained if one worked with the [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Properties_and_theorems) instead of the Fourier one.